# Referring to a C function pointer with or without '&'?

Tags: c, function-pointers

In C, a function pointer (evidently) can be referred to with or without the `&` operator.  Is there a stylistic reason to choose one over the other?

The [following code compiles and runs](https://godbolt.org/z/8Trnr4h8r) in gcc x86-64 12.2 -Wall without any warnings:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int cb1(void) { return 1; }

int cb2(void) { return 2; }

void do_cb(int (*cb)(void)) { printf("%d\n", cb()); }

int main(void) {
    do_cb(cb1);
    do_cb(&cb2);
}
```

Comment: less is more, remove useless things, thus remove & and (*cb) on use

Comment: You should try `(******&*&*&*&**do_cb)(****&*&***cb2);`.

Comment: Then one might add `printf("%d\n", (**************************cb)());` in the function too.

Comment: I believe the pointer to a function pointer defers back to the function pointer itself. Similar to how arrays defer to the pointer to the first element.. But I could be wron ghere

Comment: I dislike closing these kind of questions as opinion-based. That's not how engineering works. If you face a choice A or B and it doesn't matter, then the professional solution isn't "just use whatever you fancy". The solution is to establish a consistent standard: we always pick choice A. If you can justify it with a rationale, then great. If you can't, then at least you are consistent. This is the difference between engineering and "art".

Comment: Although the answer to the question is kind of boring: No, I don't believe there exists any stylistic or other reason to use `&` before a function pointer. Just establish a coding standard and use the same style consistently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a reason to choose one over the other?

`&` is demanded in front of function identifiers by MISRA 2004. I like it, I think it looks nice and explicitly conveys the intent.

> MISRA C Rule 16.9 (required): A function identifier shall only be used with either a preceding '&', or with a parenthesised parameter list, which may be empty.
>
> Rationale
>
> A function identifier can implicitly convert to a pointer to a function. In certain contexts this may result in a well-formed program, but which is contrary to developer expectations. For example, if the developer writes
>
> ```
> if ( f )
> ```
>
> then it is not clear whether the intent is to test if the address of the function is NULL or if a call to the function 'f()' should be made and the brackets have been unintentionally omitted. The use of the '& (address-of)' operator will resolve this ambiguity.

From https://analyst.phyzdev.net/documentation/help/reference/misra.func.addr.htm , https://rules.sonarsource.com/cpp/RSPEC-936 .

(I think the rule was removed in MISRA 2012. I wonder what is the rationale.)

Comment: I think the rule was removed because it didn't have any rationale to begin with. It isn't always desirable to document that a function call is done through a function pointer, for example perhaps function pointers were used to create an abstraction layer or wrapper that the caller need not worry themselves about.

Comment: As for the supposed rationale quoted, it is nonsense since that's already covered by other MISRA rules. We may not use any expression in an if statement which isn't "essentially boolean", so you would have to type `if(f != NULL)` no matter.

Comment: I buy the view that "what MISRA wants, MISRA gets".  In this case, since the 2012 version dropped the (IMHO silly) rationale for including the &, I'll go with "no & is needed".  Thanks.