# Referencing a function pointer with ampersand works fine while I prefer without but using & is an indicator of referencing an address

Tags: c, function-points

The code below shows the reference to function pointer:

```
typedef int (*t_somefunc)(int,int);
int product(int, int);
int main(void) {
  t_somefunc afunc = &product; // "product" works fine without "&"
```

What do we use "&" for referencing function pointer?
See full working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef int (*t_somefunc)(int,int);
int product(int, int);

int main(void) {
  t_somefunc afunc = &product; // product without & works also
  int x2 = (*afunc)(123, 456); // call product() to calculate 123*456
  printf("x2 value is %d\n", x2);
  return 1;
}

int product(int u, int v) {
  return u*v;
}
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: I've _never_ used the `&` [in 40+ years]. IMO, it's clutter. And we get consistency with `t_somefunc afunc = product; t_somefunc bfunc = afunc;` When setting `afunc` we shouldn't have to whether `product` is the a function address or another pointer.

Comment: Similar question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73612682/referring-to-a-c-function-pointer-with-or-without/73613627#73613627

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions are automatically converted to pointers for programmer convenience.

When a function is used in an expression, it is automatically converted to a pointer to the function, unless it is the operand of `sizeof` or unary `&`. C 2018 6.3.2.1 4 says:

> A *function designator* is an expression that has function type. Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, a function designator with type “function returning *type*” is converted to an expression that has type “pointer to function returning *type*”.

(In fact, if you attempt to convert the pointer back to a function by applying `*`, the automatic conversion will happen again. You can write `t_somefunc afunc = *******************product;` and still end up with the address of `product`.)

In declarations of function parameters, a function will be automatically adjusted to be a pointer to a function. C 2018 6.7.6.3 8 says:

> A declaration of a parameter as “function returning *type*” shall be adjusted to “pointer to function returning *type*”, as in 6.3.2.1.

(This is called an adjustment because there is no value being converted; the declaration is changed to declare a pointer to a function instead of a function.)

Comment: It may be worth to add a note that function parameters are also transformed. For example `void foo( void f(int))` is a valid declaration of function taking a function pointer argument. It may help make declarations prettier without resorting to `typedef`s

Answer (score 0):

Nothing, just use the name of the function (without the `()` list of parameters) e.g.

```
double(*f_to_cal)(double);

f_to_cal = sin;  /* trigonometric sine function */

return f_to_cal(angle_deg * M_PI / 180.0);
```